# How to parse binary data ("multipart/form-data") in KOA?

Tags: koa

If I send POST-query with text options, all OK:

```
query from front-end:

const request = require("request")
const options = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost:4000/user',
 headers:    form: { data: '12345' }
 }
```

On server-side (KOA) I can get parsed data of a.m.query:

```
ctx.request.method: "POST"
ctx.request.originalUrl: "user"
ctx.request.body.data: "12345"
```

But if I send a POST query with binary data (file):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
const options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/user',
  headers: 
   {
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data},
  formData: 
   { '': 
      { value: 'fs.createReadStream("F:\\image.jpg")',
        options: 
         { filename: 'F:\\image.jpg',
           contentType: null }
 } } };
```

I don't know, how can I access for this binary data ("image.jpg) on server-part (KOA), in ctx.request have any field with this data...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `busboy` for this. [I wrote a gist for doing this](https://gist.github.com/jeffijoe/60c7a1fbf36a767477c82b9fe651fe48), but I'm going to embed it here with some comments.

Let's create a helper for parsing out the file in a promise-friendly way.

```js
// parse.js
import Busboy from 'busboy'

/**
 * Parses a single file from a Node request.
 *
 * @param  {http.IncommingRequest} req
 * @return {Promise<{ file: Stream, filename: string>}
 */
export default function parse (req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const busboy = new Busboy({
      headers: req.headers,
      limits: {
        files: 1 // allow only a single upload at a time.
      }
    })

    busboy.once('file', _onFile)
    busboy.once('error', _onError)
    req.pipe(busboy)

    function _cleanup () {
      busboy.removeListener('file', _onFile)
      busboy.removeListener('error', _onError)
    }

    function _onFile (fieldname, file, filename) {
      _cleanup()
      resolve({ file, filename })
    }

    function _onError (err) {
      _cleanup()
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

Now we need to use it. Let's assume you want to upload to AWS S3.

```js
import Koa from 'koa'
import parse from './busboy'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

const app = new Koa()

const s3 = new AWS.S3({ 
  params: { Bucket: 'myBucket' } 
})

// Assuming this is a route handler.
app.use(async (ctx) => {
  const { file, filename } = await parse(ctx.req)
  // `file` is a Stream. Pass this to S3, Azure Blob Storage or whatever you want.
  // `filename` is the file name specified by the client.
  const result = await s3.upload({
    Key: filename,
    Body: file
  }).promise()

  ctx.body = result
})
```

For brevity's sake, this is how you upload the file using `axios` on the client.

```js
// `file` is a DOM File object.
function upload (file) {
  const data = new window.FormData()
  data.append('file', file, file.name)
  return axios.post('/upload', data)
}
```